# Modify File Icon

Tags: vbscript, icons

I have a VBScript that toggles proxy ON and OFF. I'd like to change the file icon accordingly, so that when the proxy is ON the file icon is a green tick and when it's OFF the icon is a red cross (meaning that I can see whether the proxy is active or not before running the script).

How do I change the icon programmatically? Just for THAT file, not ALL VBScripts!

Comment: Thanks to Ansgar this is the final version of the script 

    Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    lnkfile = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\proxy.lnk"
    
    Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)
    
    If lnk.IconLocation = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\g.ico,0" Then
      lnk.IconLocation = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\r.ico,0"
    Else
      lnk.IconLocation = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\g.ico,0"
    End If
    lnk.Save

Thanks Again

Comment: Sorry, made a mess with my last comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the icon for a specific file. You can, however, change the icon of a specific *shortcut* to a file.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

lnkfile = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\your.lnk"

Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)
If lnk.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\some.ico" Then
  lnk.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\.ico"
Else
  lnk.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\some.ico"
End If
lnk.Save
```

If the shortcut is located in the All Users desktop folder (`C:\Users\Public\Desktop`) you need to replace `"Desktop"` with `"AllUsersDesktop"`.

Comment: I like it! But your code creates a new shortcut everytime i run it. How do i 'select' an existing lnk?

Comment: @user1375452 The code should modify an existing shortcut. However, the desktop shows the contents of both `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`. If the shortcut is located in the latter you need to use `"AllUsersDesktop"` instead of `"Desktop"`.

Comment: Works!! Thanks a lot! Mind that i had to edit the IconLocation to "C:\path\to\some.ico,0" ;) or it won't toggle from one ico to the other

Comment: [Hey, Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/08/12/how-can-i-change-the-icon-for-an-existing-shortcut.aspx) provides similar approach, not creating new shortcut