# How to integrate icon modification script with script to toggle proxy?

Tags: vbscript, icons

I refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925986/modify-file-icon). Just as in the original post I have a proxy on/off script.

Where I need help is with the inclusion of the "icon change script" (see referral post) into my already existing script, i.e. where would

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

lnkfile = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\your.lnk"

Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)
If lnk.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\some.ico" Then
  sh.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\.ico"
Else
  sh.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\some.ico"
End If
lnk.Save
```

fit into

```
Option Explicit 
Dim WSHShell, strSetting
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Determine current proxy setting and toggle to oppisite setting
strSetting = WSHShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable")
If strSetting = 1 Then 
  NoProxy
Else
  Proxy
End If

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to ON
Sub Proxy
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
  WScript.Echo "Proxy is On"
End Sub

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to OFF
Sub NoProxy 
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"
  WScript.Echo "Proxy is Off"
End Sub
```

My interpretation of your answer Ansgar

```
Option Explicit 
Dim WSHShell, strSetting
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Determine current proxy setting and toggle to oppisite setting
strSetting = WSHShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable")

lnkfile = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\proxypal.lnk"
Set lnk = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)
If strSetting = 1 Then
  WSHShell.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\on.ico"
  NoProxy
Else
  WSHShell.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\off.ico"
  Proxy
End If
lnk.Save

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to ON
Sub Proxy 
  WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
  Wscript.echo "Proxy is On"
End Sub

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to OFF
Sub NoProxy 
  WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"
  Wscript.echo "Proxy is Off"
End Sub
```

However this returns this error

> line 9
>   Variable is undefined: linkfile
>   800A01F4
>   MS VBScript Runtime Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not too complicated. Just change the icon where you call the functions that modify the proxy settings:

```
...
strSetting = WSHShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable")
lnkfile = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\your.lnk"
Set lnk = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)
If strSetting = 1 Then
  WSHShell.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\enable.ico"
  NoProxy
Else
  WSHShell.IconLocation = "C:\path\to\disable.ico"
  Proxy
End If
lnk.Save
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however it returns this error
 _line 9_
 _Variable is undefined: linkfile_
 _800A01F4_
 _MS VBScript Runtime Error_ please refer to my post edit for how I implemented your code

Comment: @KrazeyboYRSA What about that error isn't clear to you? Your script uses `Option Explicit`, so you must `Dim` all variables before using them. My sample code omits that for brevity.

Comment: Again thank you for your help. I reitterate I am vbscript noob, the Option Explicit DIM pointer was not known to me. Again thnak you for your patience and help